# Trying to figure out problem with table value calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble on a HTML and JS practice project I'm working on, in where the following function is meant to calculate the total expense cost for the user. The program gave me an error for the date[i], which I then defined as one set of the td elements of the table (which the dates were listed under using the debugger). However, it then gave me another issue with a different function, stating that:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.[object HTMLTableCellElement]' is not a valid selector.

I worry that I'm running in circles for this, and I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Pastebin with full code: https://pastebin.com/My3xzyS4

Code most relevant:

```
function calcClass(sumClass) {
    var sumFields  = document.querySelectorAll("." + sumClass); //this is the one giving me issues
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sumFields.length; i++) {
      var itemValue = parseFloat(sumFields[i].value);
      if(!isNaN(itemValue)) {
        sumTotal += itemValue;
      }
    }
    return sumTotal;
  }

function calcExp() {  
    var expTable = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp tr");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < expTable.length; i++) {
      var date = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp td");
      document.getElementById("subtotal"+ [i]).value = formatNumber(calcClass(date[i]), 2);
    }
    document.getElementById("transTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass(trans), 2);
    document.getElementById("lodgeTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass(lodge), 2);
    document.getElementById("mealTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass(meal), 2);
    document.getElementById("otherTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass(other), 2);
    document.getElementById("expTotal").value = formatUSCurrency(calcClass(sum));
   }

function formatNumber(val, decimals) {
   return val.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: decimals, 
                                         maximumFractionDigits: decimals});
}

function formatUSCurrency(val) {
   return val.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"} );
```

Comment: Where you call `calcClass` you should pass the class as a string. The very first call you do, which is where you get the error, you pass instead `date[i]`. This has the value from the previous `document.getquerySelectorAll`, and is an object.

Answer (score 0):

I see the way you are doing the sums: horizontal, per date, and vertical, per item. Now, your `calcClass` function takes a class *name* as input, which is a string. Instead, what you are passing every time is a variable. In the first instance the variable is actually an object. Hence the error: an object cannot be used as a query selector.

#### Why is it an object?

Why is that an object? Because the last time you used `date`, it was as a variable to hold the result of `document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp td")` which returns a list of objects.

Now, you have a similar problem in the next calls you do to `calcClass`.

### Fix

The fix is actually pretty easy, given the way you have already cleverly structured your table: simply make those strings, as they are meant to be. So, something like this should work.

```
function calcExp() {
    var expTable = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp tr");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < expTable.length; i++) {
      // var date = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp td");  // likely not needed
      document.getElementById("subtotal" + i).value = formatNumber(calcClass('date' + i), 2);
    }
    document.getElementById("transTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass('trans'), 2);
    document.getElementById("lodgeTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass('lodge'), 2);
    document.getElementById("mealTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass('meal'), 2);
    document.getElementById("otherTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass('other'), 2);
    document.getElementById("expTotal").value = formatUSCurrency(calcClass('sum'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have the error is that you're putting an element from `querySelectorAll` but your `calcClass` function receives a string argument and query again with `querySelectorAll`. It seems like you need to pass `'date'+[i]` to calcClass and let the function partial(daily) sum of each costs.

After that, I've countered another error `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#352:54'>352:54</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"`. You're iterating `expTable.length` times but only has 6 rows. I put `6` directly to the for loop and you need to replace this number.

```js
"use strict";
 
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript 6th Edition
   Tutorial 13
   Case Problem 2
 
   Author: 4terrabytes
   Date:  7/27/2020  
 
   Filename: dl_expenses.js
 
   Function List
   =============
 
   validateSummary()
      Validates the data entry in the summary field.
 
   calcClass(sumClass)
      Sums up all of the data values for elements of the sumClass class.
 
   calcExp()
      Calculates the travel expenses from all categories and dates.
 
   formatNumber(val, decimals)
      Formats the value, "val" to the number of decimals indicated 
      by "decimals", adding thousands separators.
 
   formatUSCurrency(val)
      Formats the value, "val", as U.S. currency.
 
*/
//create an anon function
 
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
   var changingCells = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp input.sum");
   for(var i = 0; i < changingCells.length; i++) {
      changingCells[i].onchange = calcExp;
    }
    document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = validateSummary;
  });
function validateSummary(){
    var summary = document.getElementById("summary");
    if (summary.validity.valueMissing) {
      summary.setCustomValidity("You must include a summary of the trip in your report.");
    }
    else {
        summary.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }
function calcClass(sumClass) {
    var sumFields  = document.querySelectorAll("." + sumClass);
    var sumTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sumFields.length; i++) {
      var itemValue = parseFloat(sumFields[i].value);
      if(!isNaN(itemValue)) {
        sumTotal += itemValue;
      }
    }
    return sumTotal;
  }
 
function calcExp() {  

    var expTable = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp input.sum");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      var date = document.querySelectorAll("table#travelExp td");
      document.getElementById("subtotal"+ [i]).value = formatNumber(calcClass("date"+[i]), 2);
    }

    document.getElementById("transTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("trans"), 2);
    document.getElementById("lodgeTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("lodge"), 2);
    document.getElementById("mealTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("meal"), 2);
    document.getElementById("otherTotal").value = formatNumber(calcClass("other"), 2);
    document.getElementById("expTotal").value = formatUSCurrency(calcClass("sum"));
   }
 
function formatNumber(val, decimals) {
   return val.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: decimals, 
                                         maximumFractionDigits: decimals});
}
 
function formatUSCurrency(val) {
   return val.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: "currency", currency: "USD"} );
}
```

```html
//HTML Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!--
    New Perspectives on HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript 6th Edition
    Tutorial 13
    Case Problem 2
 
    Travel Expense Report
    Author: 4terrabytes
    Date:  7/27/2020 
 
    Filename: dl_expense.html
   -->
 
   <title>DeLong Enterprises Expense Report</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link href="dl_base.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
   <link href="dl_layout.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
   <script src="dl_expense.js" async></script>
 
</head>
 
<body>
   <header>
      <nav class="horizontal">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Financial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>   
      <img src="dl_logo.png" alt="DeLong Enterprises" id="logoImg" />   
   </header>
 
   <section>
     <form name="expReport" id="expReport" method="post" action="dl_valid.html">
 
      <table id="travelSummary">
         <tr>
            <th>Trip Summary<span>*</span></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <textarea id="summary" name="summary" required></textarea>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
 
      <aside>
         <h1>Expense Report</h1>
         <p>Form: 2CEXP15<br />
            * --- Required Field
         </p>
         <p>Send Report To:<br />
            Debbie Larson<br />
            Personnel Dept.<br />
            Rm. 3801<br />
            Ext. 1250
         </p>
      </aside>     
 
      <table id="empInfo">
         <tr>
            <th>Last Name<span>*</span></th>
            <th>First Name<span>*</span></th>
            <th>M.I.</th>
            <th>Account<span>*</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="accID" id="accID" pattern="^ACT\d{6}$" placeholder="ACTnnnnnn" required /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="init" id="init" required /></td>
            <th>Department<span>*</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="deptID" id="deptID" pattern="^DEPT\d{4,6}$" required placeholder="DEPTnnnnnn" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Social Security Number<span>*</span></th>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="ssn" id="ssn" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" required placeholder="nnn-nn-nnnn" /></td>
            <th>Project<span>*</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="projID" id="projID" pattern="^PROJ-[a-z]{2}-\d{3}$" required placeholder="PROJ-xx-ddd" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
 
      <table id="travelExp">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Travel Date</th>
               <th>Air &amp; Trans</th>
               <th>Lodging</th>
               <th>Meals &amp; Tips</th>
               <th>Other</th>
               <th>TOTAL</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th>SUMMARY</th>
               <td><input type="text" name="transTotal" id="transTotal" readonly /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="lodgeTotal" id="lodgeTotal" readonly /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="mealTotal" id="mealTotal" readonly /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="otherTotal" id="otherTotal" readonly /></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="expTotal" id="expTotal" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
         </tfoot>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="date" name="tDate0" id="tDate0" class="tDate" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="trans0" id="trans0" class="trans date0 sum" />
               </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="lodge0" id="lodg0" class="lodge date0 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="meal0" id="meal0" class="meal date0 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="other0" id="other0" class="other date0 sum" />
               </td>  
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subtotal0" id="subtotal0" class="subtotal" readonly />
               </td>                                            
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="date" name="tDate1" id="tDate1" class="tDate" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="trans1" id="trans1" class="trans date1 sum" />
               </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="lodge1" id="lodg1" class="lodge date1 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="meal1" id="meal1" class="meal date1 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="other1" id="other1" class="other date1 sum" />
               </td>  
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subtotal1" id="subtotal1" class="subtotal" readonly />
               </td>                                            
            </tr> 
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="date" name="tDate2" id="tDate2" class="tDate" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="trans2" id="trans2" class="trans date2 sum" />
               </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="lodge2" id="lodg2" class="lodge date2 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="meal2" id="meal2" class="meal date2 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="other2" id="other2" class="other date2 sum" />
               </td>  
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subtotal2" id="subtotal2" class="subtotal" readonly />
               </td>                                            
            </tr>  
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="date" name="tDate3" id="tDate3" class="tDate" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="trans3" id="trans3" class="trans date3 sum" />
               </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="lodge3" id="lodg3" class="lodge date3 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="meal3" id="meal3" class="meal date3 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="other3" id="other3" class="other date3 sum" />
               </td>  
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subtotal3" id="subtotal3" class="subtotal" readonly />
               </td>                                            
            </tr> 
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="date" name="tDate4" id="tDate4" class="tDate" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="trans4" id="trans4" class="trans date4 sum" />
               </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="lodge4" id="lodg4" class="lodge date4 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="meal4" id="meal4" class="meal date4 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="other4" id="other4" class="other date4 sum" />
               </td>  
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subtotal4" id="subtotal4" class="subtotal" readonly />
               </td>                                            
            </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type="date" name="tDate5" id="tDate5" class="tDate" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="trans5" id="trans5" class="trans date5 sum" />
               </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="lodge5" id="lodg5" class="lodge date5 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="meal5" id="meal5" class="meal date5 sum" />
               </td> 
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="other5" id="other5" class="other date5 sum" />
               </td>  
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subtotal5" id="subtotal5" class="subtotal" readonly />
               </td>                                            
            </tr>                                                         
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit Report" />
      </form>      
 
   </section>
 
   <footer>
      <nav class="vertical">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Travel Expenses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Information Change</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time Off Request</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Paystubs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Health Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forms/Requests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reimbursements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Grievances</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff Directory</a></li>             
          </ul>
       </nav>     
      <p>DeLong Enterprises &copy; 2018 All Rights Reserved</p>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```